# Sourcing Puppet files from outside of modules

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I'm installing a package from a module (`Nginx` in this specific case) and would like to include a configuration file from outside of the module, i.e. from a top level `files` directory parallel to the top level `manifests` directory. I don't see any way to source the file though without including it in a module or in my current Vagrant environment referring to the absolute local path.

Does Puppet allow for sourcing files from outside of modules as described in the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

if I understand your question correctly, you can.
In your module a simple code like this

```ruby
file { '/path/to/file':
    ensure => present,
    source => [
               "puppet:///files/${fqdn}/path/to/file",
               "puppet:///files/${hostgroup}/path/to/file",
               "puppet:///files/${domain}/path/to/file",
               "puppet:///files/global/path/to/file",
    ],
}
```

will do the job. The **/path/to/file** will be sourced using a file located in the "files" Puppet share.
(in the example above, it search in 4 different locations).

**update** maybe you're talking about a directory to store files which is not shared by Puppet fileserver (look at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html), and in this case you can't i think, Vagrant or not, but you can add it to your Puppet fileserver to do it. I thinks it's the best (and maybe only) way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of Vagrant VMs you can simply store files within your Vagrant project directory (containing your VagrantFile). 
This directory is usually available to all VMs as /vagrant within the VM on creation.

If you want other directories on your computer to be available to your VMs just add the following to your VagrantFile

```
# see http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html
config.vm.share_folder "v-packages", "/vagrant_packages", "../../dpkg"
```

Then to use the files within puppet you can simply treat them as local files to the VM

```
# bad example, bub basically use 'source => 'file:///vagrant/foo/bar'
file { '/opt/cassandra':
    ensure  => directory,
    replace => true,
    purge   => true,
    recurse => true,
    source  => 'file:///vagrant/conf/dist/apache-cassandra-1.2.0',
}
```

This is probably only wise to do if you only using local puppet manifests/modules.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to help [bennylope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122291/bennylope), but for others who happen across this question, as I did before figuring it out for myself ...

Include stuff like this in your Vagrantfile ...

```rb
GUEST_PROVISIONER_CONFDIR = "/example/destination/path"
HOST_PROVISIONER_CONFDIR  = "/example/source/path"
config.vm.synced_folder HOST_PROVISIONER_CONFIDIR, GUEST_PROVISIONER_CONFDIR
puppet.options = "--fileserverconfig='#{GUEST_PROVISIONER_CONFDIR}/fileserver.conf'"
```

Then make sure /example/source/path contains the referenced fileserver.conf file. It should look something like ...

```yaml
[foo]
  path /example/destination/path
  allow *
```

Now, assuming example-file.txt exists in /example/source/path, the following will work in your manifests:

```
source  => "puppet:///foo/example-file.txt",
```

See:

1. [Puppet configuration reference entry for fileserverconfig](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#fileserverconfig)
2. [Serving Files From Custom Mount Points](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html#serving-files-from-custom-mount-points)