# puppet file resource, how to point to source

Tags: puppet

When referring to a file resource on the puppet master, does it have to reside under the modulepath?  The docs [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-source) seem to indicate it.

The file I'm using was put under the `profiles` folder instead.  I'm trying to refer to it like this:

```
source  =>  puppet:///profiles/a_subfolder/myfile
```

(The physical path on the box is `/profiles/files/a_subfolder/myfile`)

I'm not having any luck so far and wanted to confirm that I can point a file resource somewhere besides the modulepath, and that my URI is correct.

Also, if my subfolder doesn't exist yet on the puppet agent, do I need to set some extra flags to both create the folder path and put the file in place? Here's what I have now:

```
    ensure  =>  'present',
    source  =>  'puppet:///profiles/a_subfolder/myfile',
    mode    =>  '0755',
    owner   =>  'specialuser'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sourcing Puppet files from outside of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518905/sourcing-puppet-files-from-outside-of-modules)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution worked..

source  =>  'puppet:///modules/profiles/',

in your case -

source  =>  'puppet:///modules/profiles/a_subfolder/myfile',

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to puppet but as far as I understood you need to set up a puppet file server if you want to use `puppet://` URIs.

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file to get from your puppet master, please do the following:
1) create the folder on you puppet master. Let's take it as /opt/puppet_dev
2) edit /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf and add:
    [puppet_dev]
        path /opt/puppet_dev
        allow *
3) In your manifest write:
    file { '/opt/on_my_node/slave_path':
        source => "puppet:///puppet_dev/my_folder_I_want_to_move",
        ensure => present,
     }
4) restart puppetmaster service ( you change fileserver, I recommend to restart) and run the agent.

- Note: you can control the recurse and the recursive limit with file. Always use this when writing puppet: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html

Hopes this is what your were looking for :)